# Do functions $f$ in $F(-\infty,\infty)$ that satisfy $f(-x)=f(x)$ form a subspace of $F(-\infty,\infty)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the general vector space, $F(-\infty,\infty)$, denoted V. Do even functions, $f(-x)=f(x)$, form a subspace of v?

Comment: What have you tried?  What check do you know to make on whether a *subset* of a vector space is actually a *subspace*?

Comment: You should actually show those conditions hold, and also that the subset of even functions is not empty.  This is often overlooked because it is easy, but you should identify at least one function known to be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: 1. $af(-x)=af(x)$.
2. $(f+g)(-x)=f(-x)+g(-x)=f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)$.